# Calling a Java ee @model from a POJO

Tags: jakarta-ee, model, pojo, entitymanager

I currently have a @model class that uses a stateless session bean which has an entity manager to persist to the database. I can successfully call the @model class from an xhtml page and persist a new "task" to the database with the following:

## {index.createTask()}

but when I try to do something similar from a java class by just calling a function in the model class, it fails!

Any idea why/what I am doing wrong?

I am new to java ee and stackoverflow so I appologise in advance if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

So by

> when I try to do something similar from a java class

you mean you access e.g. `createTask()` from a plain java class which gets started via some java main class?

If so, then you don't have a container available which does all the necessary work for you around persisting an entity. 
You can use entity classes and JPA outside a container in J2SE, but then you have to create the entity manager yourself.